# video preview is showing black screen - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, camera, iphone11

My app is working to capture video from camera but on iPhone 11 devices video preview initial screen is showing black. Video plays in preview well only first snapshot of preview is black.
Following is my code:-

```
if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {
            if type == .video {
                self.cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera
                self.cameraPicker.allowsEditing = false
                self.cameraPicker.delegate = self
                self.cameraPicker.mediaTypes =  [kUTTypeMovie as String]
                self.cameraPicker.cameraCaptureMode = (type == .video) ? .video : .photo
                present(self.cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: {})
            } 
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you added the camera privacy setting for the app in Settings

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes camera privacy setting is added and it's working perfectly on all other devices. Not working only on iPhone 11 family.